# How can I git diff markdown (.md) files

Tags: git, markdown

I have some markdown files but I can't git diff them.

No result at the command line and not supported in `gitg` (visual git)

Is that possible with the files as they are, without converting them to something else?

Comment: Does [this SO answer help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5999495/using-an-alternate-diff-algorithm-in-git)?

Comment: Is it in a git repository?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should work fine; markdown files are plaintext files, so `git diff` is perfect.

This could be one of a few possible things:

1. There is no difference in the file (empty output).
2. The changes to the files have not been added (`git add -p *.md`)

What does `git status` say? If it doesn't contain a few lines that say something like "modified: something.md" or "new file: something.md" then you're not going to get a diff.

**EDIT:** These files are actually *in* a git repo right? If not, just use Unix's normal diff utility (`man diff` for more info).